# How to retrieve GET variables with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a page with the following format : http://www.test.com/get.php?pSuccess=success
I need to retrieve the `pSuccess` value using jQuery.
I tried with the following code but I can't get it working..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function GetURLParameter(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}​
var success = GetURLParameter('pSuccess');

});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I use this native function:

```
function pget( name ){
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp ( regexS );
  var tmpURL = window.location.href;
  var results = regex.exec( tmpURL );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}
```

In this case `pget('pSuccess')` gives the correct value.

Comment: is it right to use this code on the $(document).ready(function() ?

Comment: Yes, you have to declare this function before.